# Auto-coloring plots with multiple panels?

Tags: plotting, graphics

There must be an easy way to plot these with the correct colors from the legend?

```
funs = Flatten@Table[x^i Sin[j x], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 3}];
Plot[Evaluate@funs, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 Frame -> True, PlotLayout -> {"Row", 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a bug, considering that the legend does contain all the colors. I would report this to Support (support@wolfram.com). It also doesn't seem possible to change the colors using `PlotStyle`, which is a bit strange

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might not be the prettiest workaround, but at least it works:

```
funs = Flatten@Table[x^i Sin[j x], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 3}];
Plot[
 Evaluate@MapIndexed[Style[#, ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]] &, funs], {x, 
  0, 2 Pi},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", Frame -> True, PlotLayout -> {"Row", 3}
 ]
```

[image]

The idea is to use `Style[...]` wrappers to force `Plot` to apply the desired colors